# How to align middle column in responsive 3-column structure?

Tags: css, html

I have an HTML form with several English sentences, visually presented as one sentence per row.  In the middle of each of these sentences there is a `<select>` dropdown, the left and right edges of which need to be aligned across multiple rows to make it look cleaner:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column col1"> <p> Choose something: </p> </div>
    <div class="column col2"> <select name="dropdown"> ... options ... </select> </div>
    <div class="column col3"> <p> and finish the sentence.</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column col1"> <p> Choose something else: </p> </div>
    <div class="column col2"> <select name="dropdown2"> ... options ... </select> </div>
    <div class="column col3"> <p> and finish another sentence.</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column col1"> <p> Choose last thing: </p> </div>
    <div class="column col2"> <select name="dropdown3"> ... options ... </select> </div>
    <div class="column col3">
        <p>
            and all dropdowns should be left- and right-aligned if
            there is space.  This longer third column should get broken
            onto a second line below the second dropdown if it can't fit
            immediately to the right of the other two.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However it's a responsive layout, and I only want to fix the width of the middle column, and have the 1st and 3rd columns automatically expand/contract according to the following design criteria:

- As many `column` elements as possible in each `row` should be placed side-to-side, depending on the viewport width.
- As many `col2` elements as possible should be left-aligned.

In the above, the first takes priority to the second; in other words, if we start with a browser viewport wide enough to accommodate both criteria:

1. As the browser viewport width is reduced, the first width to shrink should be the 3rd column, preserving `col2` alignment and keeping all three `column` elements side-by-side.
2. If shrinking the 3rd column to its minimum width isn't enough, the 1st column should start shrinking, which will at some point break alignment but still keep elements side-by-side.
3. If that's still not enough, the whole `col3` block within any row which is still too wide should move below the `col1` and `col2` blocks.  Now `col3` is no longer side-by-side with `col1` and `col2`, but this sacrifice means that we can restore `col2` alignment.  (At this point `col1`'s `max-width` will prevent an undesirable gap between the beginning of the sentence and the dropdown.)

Based on the first two rules, clearly anything which uses percentages isn't going to work.  And presumably due to the 3rd rule, anything which uses `<table>` won't work either.

Any margins / padding can be assumed to be fixed.  `overflow: hidden` would break the English sentence, so there cannot be height restrictions on the `<p>` elements.

I've waded through countless HTML/CSS articles and SO questions but so far not found anything which explains how to achieve this.  Here's a starting point for you to play around with:

- http://jsfiddle.net/aspiers/Bdq8Q/5/

Solutions involving HTML5 or newer functionality in CSS are greatly preferred to JavaScript-based hacks.  It's OK for solutions to change the HTML, although I'd love to know if it was possible only via CSS.  Thanks!

Comment: Would your use case allow for the minimum widths of the columns to be predefined in CSS? Or must the minimum widths be calculated based on the content? If they can be statically defined in CSS, then this dynamic layout changing can be achieved via CSS media-queries min/max-width as well as utilizing floats.

Comment: Minimum widths *could* be predefined, but I'd be rather disappointed with HTML5 / CSS if this was necessary or if the only solution involved media queries ;-)  Although I'd still be interested to see such a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Does `col2` have a fixed width for the sole purpose of aligning the left/right edges, or does it need a fixed width for a different reason as well?

Comment: It contains <select> dropdowns, so the fixed width is mainly for alignment.

Comment: Can you provide mockups of the expected result? Also, can you please explain how your jsfiddle is close, but not quite what you want? This question is a little difficult to decipher and these items will make it a lot easier to find a solution.

Comment: The jsfiddle already provides that. The second column is not aligned.

Comment: But what are `col1` and `col3` supposed to look like once the alignment is achieved? Are all the `col1` elements to have the same width to achieve alignment, or is the gap between `col1` and `col2` supposed to shrink/grow to achieve alignment? And when `col3` gets pushed down, are `col1` and `col2` to keep their widths, or are they to expand to use the entire width of the row? Does `col3` expand to use the entire width as well? Lastly, when `col1` and `col3` expand/shrink: Is their text overflow to be visible by simply expanding the height of the row, or is the overflow to be hidden?

Comment: And why do you have `max-width` settings on your `col1` and `col3` elements? What are these meant to achieve?

Comment: All fair questions.  Yes, all `col1` elements are supposed to be the same width in order to align `col2` if the browser viewport is big enough.  This is about growing shrinking columns, not margins or padding - the latter should remain fixed.  When `col3` gets pushed down, `col1` should expand to its `max-width`, which is there to prevent there being too much space between the right edge of content in `col1` and the left edge of the input field in `col2`, since like I said, in each row, the three columns form an English sentence.  I'll edit the question to clarify all this.

Comment: The `max-width` on `col3` is not important and could be dropped; the main focus of the question is the left-alignment of `col2`.  It's an English sentence, so hiding overflow is not acceptable - I would suggest also having a `min-width` and no height restrictions on `col1` / `col3`.

Comment: I think you'll have to use javaScript for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the JavaScript/JQuery approach, I'll provide an idea, but not the code itself.
my code sections are not real code, but illustration of what need to be done. (except for the CSS part)

first, we set the box-sizing of all the elements in page to be border-box, because its easier to calculate the sizes of the elements this way.

```
*
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

this means that the width of .col2 have to grow by 10px to support the 10px padding and stay like before.

```
.col2
{
    width: 120px;
}
```

it will be best if the second column will always be next to the first one,
so we will set the max-width of .col1 to support that behaviour.

```
.col1
{
    max-width: calc(100% - 136px); /*136 = 120 + 2*5 + 2*3*/
}
```

in the entire process, we wont set anything to .row & .col3 width.
the row can shrink or grow, and .col3 will always take the exact amount of space it needs
(regardless if he's aligned with .col1 & .col2 or in a different line) so actually we only change .col1 width.

when the page firstly loads, and every time the body resizes we will call a javaScript function that finds the best layout.

```
function adjustToBestLayout()
{
    1.
    2.
    3.
    4.
}
```

in the process, we'll need to know what would be the actual size of .col1 & .col3 elements in the current viewport size (.col2 is fixed so it helps)
if we wouldn't apply the script because their width depends on their content and may change in different viewport sizes.

so if its the first time we enter the function, we will "save" our clean layout, as it is, without the script intervenience.
and later, each time we enter the function, we will replace the old adjusted layout with the clean one, and readjust it again from scratch.

so it goes something like this:

**1** bring back the "clean" layout.
now in each row we have the folowing:
.col1 & .col2 are aligned, each taking exactly the size of its content,
and .col3 (also taking exactly the size of its content) can be in one of two possible state,
he can be aligned with the two first column, or in a new line.

**2** each column element will save his actual width in a property called ActualWidth for later use

**3** for each row, we will calculate the AvailableWidth and save it as a property for later use,the calculation will be:

```
if(row.width >= row.col1.ActualWidth + row.col2.ActualWidth + row.col3.ActualWidth)
{
    //in this case, all columns are in the same line, and we possibly have space left
    row.AvailableWidth = row.width - (row.col1.ActualWidth + row.col2.ActualWidth + row.col3.ActualWidth);
}
else
{
    //in this case, the third column is in a different line,
    row.AvailableWidth = row.width - (row.col1.ActualWidth + row.col2.ActualWidth);
}
```

the best layout will be found when we will stretch as much as .col1 element to the same width,
so we will try to strech the little .col1 to the size of a bigger .col1 element in the layout.
but without causing any .col3 element to get down to a new line,
so we can strech each .col1 element only by his row.AvailableWidth or less.

**4** find the best width to give to the .col1 elements by this calculation:
for each .col1 we will count how many rows will get aligned if we stretch the other .col1 to his size.
and finnaly we will take the one that scored the maximum number.
so, for each .col1.ActualWidth (=CurrentWidth): how many rows return true to this statement

```
0 <= CurrentWidth - row.col1.CurrentWidth <= row.AvailableWidth
```

after that, we fix the width of .col1 elements to the wining width
(only in the rows that return true to the previous statement)

***Et voilà!***

Finnaly: if i were you, I would prefered a "Table-Like" somewhat "fixed" layout.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your effort on this!  Quite a lot more complicated than what I'd hoped for, though.  I'll digest and try to give it a go.  I'd be interested to hear more about what you meant by your last comment, too.

Comment: I simply meant, that you should fix the .col1 width (width %, or using calc) causing his height to grow with content. and forget about this fluid 'almost un-do-able' layout.. lol.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with the following CoffeeScript solution:

```
fixSizes = ->
    col1_min = parseInt $(".col1").css("min-width")
    col1_max = parseInt $(".col1").css("max-width")
    console.log "min #{col1_min}, max #{col1_max}"
    $(".row").each (i, row) =>
        debug = false
        r = $(row)
        row_width   = r.width()
        col1_width  = r.find(".col1").width()
        col1_outer  = r.find(".col1").outerWidth(true)
        col2_outer  = r.find(".col2").outerWidth(true)
        col3_outer  = r.find(".col3").outerWidth(true)
        col1_spacing = col1_outer - col1_width
        space_for_col1 = row_width - col1_spacing - col2_outer - col3_outer
        if i == 1
            debug = true
        if debug
            console.log "row#{i} #{row_width}, col1 #{space_for_col1}, col1s #{col1_spacing}, col2 #{col2_outer}, col3 #{col3_outer}"
        col1 = r.find(".col1")
        col3 = r.find(".col3")
        if space_for_col1 < col1_min
            # Can't shrink col1 enough to fit all onto one line; break
            # col3 onto new line.
            col1.css("width", "#{col1_max}px")
            col3.css("clear", "left")
            if debug
                console.log "    break into two lines"
        else if space_for_col1 < col1_max
            # Shrink col1 to fix all onto one line.  Annoyingly we
            # need to shrink by an extra pixel in order to ensure that
            # col3 has enough room to go on the top line and doesn't
            # float directly underneath col2.  This is presumably due
            # to rounding errors, since the row width is a float (in
            # Chrome at least).
            col1.css("width", "#{Math.floor(space_for_col1)-1}px")
            col3.css("clear", "")
            if debug
                console.log "    shrink col1"
        else
            # No shrinking required, ensure col2 is aligned.
            col1.css("width", "#{col1_max}px")
            col3.css("clear", "")
            if debug
                console.log "    fix col1 to align col2"

jQuery ->
    fixSizes()
    $(window).resize ->
        fixSizes()
```

It works except for an annoying flicker when shrinking the window width in Chrome - for a split second, `col3` floats under immediately `col2`, before the Javascript shrinks `col1` sufficiently for it to float back up to the right of `col2`.

This just feels ugly though.  I can't help feeling there must be something more elegant.